# Change iFrame src on ajax complete

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe

using jQuery's $.ajax() I want to retrieve some information from the server, and then, based on that info, change the src attribute of an iframe.

Something like:

```
$.ajax(
                {
                    url: "someUrl.aspx/getInfo",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: "{'data':{'data1':'data1'}}",
                    type: "post",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    complete: function(data, stat) {
                        if (stat == "success" ) 
                        {
                           var src = JSON.parse(jsondata.responseText).d.src
                           $('#myframe').attr("src",src);
                        } 

                    }
                }
                );
```

The page I am trying to load is returning a PDF file, so the goal is to show the user the dialog to choose between downloading or opening that file. On IE7 and 8 the browser is showing the info bar with this message : "To help protect your security, Internet Explorer blocked this site from downloading files to your computer. Click here for options."

Changing the iframe's src attribute OUTSIDE the ajax call works fine and the dialog to choose between opening or saving the PDF is shown.

Any workarounds to avoid the info bar showing? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any way you can use something other than an iframe? You really should avoid them. Post your html.

Comment: Can't figure out any other way, the "src" I am trying to call, which returns the pdf, lives in another server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternate approach that avoids both an iframe and the info bar is to simply not open the PDF automatically. In the call AJAX callback, create a regular link to the PDF file so the user can click on it directly. This should prevent IE from flagging the download.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the link's href dynamically on the AJAX callback and made the link look like a "print" button (via jQuery UI).

Comment: @mentxugle can you pls elaborate bit more in detail on how you achieved this with sample code.. ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this if you don't want to use jQuery

`document.getElementById("myframe").src=src;`

try this wit jQuery

```
var iframe = $('#myframe');

 $(iframe).attr('src', src)
```

In order to open a PDF try this

```
window.open(src);
```

will open the pdf in a new window...but the info bar cannot be avoided....

Comment: Opening a new window on complete makes IE7 open it and then close it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it'll work, but you can try this:

```
var alterIframe = function(src){
   $('#myframe').attr("src",src);
};

$.ajax(
        {
            url: "someUrl.aspx/getInfo",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "{'data':{'data1':'data1'}}",
            type: "post",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            complete: function(data, stat) {
                if (stat == "success" ) {
                    data = $.parseJSON(data);
                    setTimeout('alterIframe("' + data.src + '")',300);
                }
            }
        }
);
```

I hope this helps you ;)

Comment: Thank you, but still getting the same behaviour: IE7 showing the info bar.